# How do I make this function reload instead of pause?

Tags: javascript, refresh, reload

I want my links listed in this function to reload the contents, not pause. how do I revise?

```
function pause(index) {
  for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
    if (ids[i].index == index) {
      playCmd(ids[i].id);
    }
  }
}
```

I tried function `reload(index)` and it just refreshes the entire page.

Comment: Javascript is not java, you shouldn't include that tag.

Comment: `pause(...)` and `reload(...)` are just function names in this case. You can call it `function icecreamrabbit(index){}` if you want. Please describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: What do you mean by reload?

Comment: `reload()` is `window.reload()`, which refreshes the page.

Comment: There are no links in that function.